# Adding new field in the database in Yii 1.1

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have added a field `allergy` in the `user` table. But after submitting the form it is not get inserted. I am new to Yii. I am not using any Gii generators since this is the existing code base. Is it possible to add the new field as I tried here or should I run any Yii generators (model,CRUD)

I changed the following areas.

**\protected\views\userManagement\user.php**

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'allergy'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'allergy'); ?>
```

**\protected\models\User.php**

```
In the attributeLabels() function: 

'allergy' => 'Allergy',

In the search() function: 

$criteria->compare('allergy',$this->allergy);

In the beforeSave() function: 

if($this->allergy=='')
  $this->setAttribute('allergy', NULL);     
else
  $this->setAttribute('allergy', $this->allergy);
```

Comment: Do you have any rules for it? You need at least one rule. If you don't need a validator for it, use `safe` as the rule.

Comment: No I don't have any rules let me add and check

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you saved my time :)